# How can i add links to other pages in reStructuredText?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx to create a documentation for my project, but i'm struggling to understand basic concepts about RST.

So i have a basic project with an `index.rst` and i'm using the `sphinx-rtd-theme` to style it. So i created the html and on the left i have a menu, just like [here](https://sphinx-tutorial.readthedocs.io/step-1/#code-samples). Now i created a new page for the documentation, and the rst file is called `auth.rst`.

What i don't understand is how do i add links to other pages such as `auth.rst` in the side menu on the left? Right now, i have on that menu two links: **Welcome to Test-API's documentation!** and **Indices and tables**, how do i add new links to other pages of my documentation? I don't understand where is this defined in the code below and i didn't find much about this

```
Welcome to Test-API's documentation!
================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath the ':caption ...' you write the relative path (from where this RST file is on disk) to the target rst (auth.rst in your case)

Example, given this folder structure:

```
RST
  |- a.rst
  |- b.rst
  |-folder2 
    |-c.rst
    |-d.rst
```

In a, if I wanted to reference b and c, I could have:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
   b
   folder2/c
```

And if I wanted to reference d from c, I would do this in c:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
   d
```